# How do I loop through a dataframe and only loop through unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, smtplib

I apologize in advanced for the poor title name.

I am trying to automate an email task. I need to send emails associated with a specific process. I have no idea how to properly loop through the dataframe.  I do not wish to end emails for each task, just the process.

Do I need to groupby? I am genuinely confused how this needs to be done.

```
   Process ID Task Execution Date Execution Time Start Date Start Time  End Date End Time   Status               Emails Process Status
0           A    1       8/7/2019        1:00 PM   8/7/2019    1:00 PM  8/7/2019  1:05 PM  Success                  NaN  Successful
1           A    2       8/7/2019        1:05 PM   8/7/2019    1:05 PM  8/7/2019  1:10 PM  Success                  NaN  Successful
2           A    3       8/7/2019        1:10 PM   8/7/2019    1:10 PM  8/7/2019  1:15 PM  Success  ['user1@gmail.com']  Successful
3           B    1       8/7/2019        2:00 PM   8/7/2019    2:00 PM  8/7/2019  2:05 PM  Success                  NaN     FAILED
4           B    2       8/7/2019        2:05 PM   8/7/2019    2:05 PM  8/7/2019  2:10 PM  Success  ['user2@gmail.com']     FAILED
5           B    3       8/7/2019        2:10 PM   8/7/2019    2:10 PM  8/7/2019  2:15 PM   FAILED                  NaN     FAILED
```

```
for process in df['Process ID'].unique():
    print(df['Execution Date'])

        msg = print(Process ID + ‘was’ + DAG Status.  Process ID + ‘was completed on’ + End Date (on task 3) + at End Time (on task 3)).  

        server = smtplib.SMTP('sever.com')
        server.sendmail(
        'my_email@gmail.com',
        df.['Emails'],
        msg)
        server.quit()
```

The desired output will be  an email being sent that states.

`A was Succesful.  A was completed on 8/7/2019 at 1:15pm.`

`B was FAILED. B was completed on 8/7/2019 at 2:15pm`

Comment: for better answers indicate what's the desired output explicitly

Comment: @yuca I included one desired output.

Comment: What is your aggregation rule for some group of processes? E.g. process B has successes and failures. What then?

Comment: @ifly6  If you see, the last column is `Process Status`,the process B has FAILED since one task has failed.  If all tasks are succesful. `Process Status == Successful`. If one tasks fails, `Process Status == FAILED`

Comment: Do you mean if any failed that group of processes has failed?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @ifly6

Answer (score 0):

How I'm interpreting your problem is that you actually want to get from your jumble of data to the level where you have a flag, `all(result_set in [True, False])`, for each process ID. Then, you want to take that data and do something with it.

To get to that aggregate level, do this:

```
df['process_failed'] = df['Process Status'] == 'FAILED'  # consider case insensitive
result_set = df.groupby('Process ID')['process_failed'].any().rename('any_process_id_failed')
```

I chose to generate an intermediate variable because the GroupBy accessors don't play elegantly with strings (absent some apply invocations).

From this output, loop through each of them to do whatever you need to do to make your emails. Pandas isn't an email client, barring a truly long run invocation of Zawinski's law, so that's outside the scope of your question.